# Delphi XE 2 Crashing on Startup

Tags: delphi, crash, delphi-xe2

I just installed Delphi XE 2 and went through the whole installation process; however, when I try to launch Delphi XE 2, I get the following error messages, and then nothing happens (Delphi XE 2 crashes or something and fails and no screens appear). I have already tried repairing, uninstalling and then reinstalling.

**Error Message 1:**

[image: http://i41.tinypic.com/25m4y.jpg]

**Error Message 2:**

[image: http://i43.tinypic.com/2i1mfma.jpg]

**Error Message 3 + 4:**

[image: http://i41.tinypic.com/j6n410.jpg]

Did something fail to register during the installation process?  Any ideas on how to remedy this issue?

I have also asked this question on Embarcadero's forums, but have yet to receive an answer.  A bit of Googling revealed that this problem was asked before on Embarcadero's forums, but the link is now dead.

Comment: 'The link is now dead' - do you have the link URL?

Comment: @mjn: When doing this search: https://www.google.com/search?q=delhpi+xe+2+start+up+item+not+found, the first set of useful results are all dead links. Such as this one: https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=51545

Comment: Contact emba support. They will help.

Comment: @Ivan, sometimes you can find expired content on google's cache (for a time at least), see [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:CFFSQBwuE6QJ:https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa%3FthreadID%3D51545&hl=en&strip=1)

Comment: See https://newsgroups.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=421366 - many forum articles have been deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get Delphi to install correctly, I needed to install a few .NET 3.5-4.0 updates (apparently these were not marked for automatic download and installation), reboot, uninstall Delphi XE 2, and run the Delphi XE 2 installer as an Administrator.

After doing this, Delphi XE 2 worked without a hitch.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the IDE as an Administrator, or did you run the installer as an Administrator?

I have actually seen this error (The first one, specifically) before, and the solution was to run the installer with admin rights so that certain .NET assemblies could be registered correctly.

Comment: I tried uninstalling and then reinstalling as an Administrator as well as running the IDE as an administrator and it still gives the errors.